# Setting editor in mutt: vim with parameters?

Tags: vim, mutt, editors

I am exploring mutt as an email client - and I like it very much - my only problem is setting the editor to be vim with some extra parameters.  Ideally, I would like something like

```
set editor='vim -c "set fo+=aw"'
```

but this doesn't work: after editing a message and then saving and quitting, mutt responds with an error about "aborted unmodified message".  If I use

```
set editor=vim
```

then everything works fine.  How can I pass parameters to vim via the `set editor` command in `.muttrc`?

Comment: does mutt launch vim with a specific filetype? if so, you could try defining an autocommand that runs `set fo+=aw` when the mutt files are loaded

Comment: I have used a similar setting for years without any problem.  Also, your exact command seems to work fine here, and so does moving the `set` command to a `ftplugin` for `mail`.

Answer (score 5):

I've had the following in my `~/.vimrc` for years:

```
autocmd BufNewFile,BufRead /tmp/mutt* set noautoindent filetype=mail wm=0 tw=78 nonumber digraph nolist
autocmd BufNewFile,BufRead ~/tmp/mutt* set noautoindent filetype=mail wm=0 tw=78 nonumber digraph nolist
```

They tell `vim` to set those options when editing matching files.

It works well for me.  The only thing I'd consider adding would be to set `paste` as well as `noautoindent`.

BTW, I write all my email in `mutt` with `vim` - I wouldn't/couldn't use anything else....even when I had to use Icedove (aka Thunderbird) at $a_previous_job years ago to connect to their Exchange server, I had the External Editor plugin installed so I could use `gvim`.   I eventually switched to using `mutt`+`vim`+`fetchmail` - direct imap connections to the Exchange server timed out in about 60 seconds, nowhere long enough to write anything but the shortest msg in `vim`.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a shell script to hold the options, and set your `editor` variable to that.

For example

```
#!/bin/sh
vim -c "set fo+=aw" "$@"
```

The [Mutt FAQ](https://dev.mutt.org/trac/wiki/MuttFaq/Editor) suggests a similar approach in *How to trim quoted replies (like stripping signatures)?*, though this is not generally material for an FAQ.